# Error: migration -> adding a new column to a table in Entity Framework Core

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, migration

I have a working App, with some objects, database, etc. Everything working fine. I built it with ASP .NET CORE and Entity Framework Core 1.0. I am using "Code First".

Now I want to add a new property (userID) to the tables contact and organization.

here is what I have done:

1- I added it in the model Contact.cs and Organization.cs like this:

```
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
```

2- I ran a migration:

```
c...\ContactManagement> dotnet ef migrations add userID
```

and I got a new migration file.

3- I try to update the Database and I get this error:

```
**The index 'IX_Tags_ContactId' is dependent on column 'ContactId'
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ContactId failed because one or more objects access this column**
```

And that's it. I do no go over this point.

I do not understand what has to do the new column with an old column that was working OK.

I have read here in Stackoverflow that I have to delete constrains, but looking into the database tables there is not constrains to delete.

Any idea, what is going on?

Comment: Have you managed to resolve the issue. If not it seems you need profile queries you got in `SQL server`

Comment: No, I did not.
So, I started the database creation for scratch including the desired new column